# Horizontal scaling with asp net core SignalR app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an asp net core signalR app in my docker swarm config with a Redis backplane.

I need to get all connections to my app

With only 1 replica, I can create a list like this:

```
public static readonly List<string> Connected = new();
```

I can add/remove users from this list when they connect/disconnect;
this method is working fine. However, when I scale up by adding an instance, this stops working.

Question: how I can check if a user is connected as I scale horizontally?

I read [this signalr guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections?ranMID=46131) and I like the implementation through the database, but can I cannot understand how to validate the connection on a server restart.

For example:
2 servers, 1 Redis, 1 DB with connection
All fine, but if 1 server crashes, it will not trigger `OnDisconnectedAsync`
in the hub, so I will not be able to remove connections from the DB.

Comment: See example https://github.com/hgmauri/signalr-socket-dotnet5